# Getting an error when trying to add component to AppController in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Im trying to add a SessionComponent to my controller in order to able to change the language of my app on the fly. The following snippet (specifically line 3) is the code i've tried according to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#using-components

```
class AppSettingsController extends AppController
{
    var $components = array('Session');
```

But when i try to run any of the actions of my Controller i get:

```
SessionComponent could not be found.

Create the class SessionComponent below in file:         
src/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php
```

As if the SessionComponent doesn't exist. All answers i have been able to find say that what i have already done ought to work. Do you have any idea what i might have missed or what i should look into to fix it?

Comment: Which CakePHP Version do you have? In CakePHP v2.7. the FlashComponent was added for the  SessionComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post I conclude that you are referred to a **CakePHP 2** documentation, but error message telling us that you are using **CakePHP 3**!

> **src**/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php

**cakephp 3 has the following components:**

- Authentication
- Cookie
- Cross Site Request Forgery
- Flash
- Security
- Pagination
- Request Handling

and here is how to use sessions in your application:

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object**

Comment: Thank you! I was accidentally looking at the wrong documentation (i.e. the 2.x book).